# How did Kovacs get Mary Lou's stack?

Tags: altered-carbon

[image]
<sup>(Episode #9 Rage in Heaven)</sup>

In season 1 episode 9 Kovacs gives Mary Lou's stack to his sister Rei while faking his apathy for all of it.

Mary Lou's stack was taken by Ortega much earlier in the series, and Ortega is now already with Rei being tortured.

When did the exchange between Ortega and Kovacs take place? I must have missed it.

Two pages on Wikia and an article were not helpful:

- https://altered-carbon.fandom.com/wiki/Mary_Lou_Henchy
- https://altered-carbon.fandom.com/wiki/Cortical_Stack
- https://screenrant.com/altered-carbon-season-1-finale-twists-spoilers/

Answer (score 3):

[image]

After some timeline scrubbing, I've found the exchange. It's in episode 5 "[The Wrong Man](https://altered-carbon.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wrong_Man)".

After sleeping together Oretga hands it over and explains her motive for taking it (in case the day comes and they're allowed to spin Mary Lou up).

Though in the scene she doesn't ask him to do anything with it. She gets a call from [Mickey](https://altered-carbon.fandom.com/wiki/Mickey) that interrupts them; Dimi has been resleeved, and they head to interrogate him.